# hide/show table row via multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect

Currently I'm working on filtering table using bootstrap-multiselect plugin. I'm having hard time to make it work properly. I want to show/hide table row depending on selected values in multiselect. E.g. If row has a value of **Activated**, then only row with activated value should be shown and others will be hidden. If I selected Activated and Deactivated then row with values **Activated** and **Deactivated** will be shown. If I selected **All Selected**, all row should shown. Checked my code here:

```
$('#custom-select').multiselect({
       includeSelectAllOption: true,
       onChange: function(option, checked) {

       var selected = [];

       $('#custom-select option:selected').each(function() {
           selected.push($(this).val());
       });

       console.log(selected);

       $.each(selected, function(i, val) {   

          $('#custom-table tr > td:not(:contains('+val+'))').closest('tr').hide();
          $('#custom-table tr > td:contains('+val+')').closest('tr').show();

       //console.log(val);
       });

       }
   });
```

My current work on **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h0Lfjqs/)**.

Comment: This will probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204619/jquery-multiple-select-show-hide  esp the last jsfiddle on this page.

Comment: @vanburenx Getting idea on this example, but it uses classes not cell value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hiding table rows `tr` inside each loop. So, last time the loop runs, it hides the rows which it was supposed to show. Take that out of the loop and hide all the rows before performing `show`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#custom-select').multiselect({
       includeSelectAllOption: true,
       onChange: function(option, checked) {

           var selected = [];

           $('#custom-select option:selected').each(function() {
               selected.push($(this).val());
           });

           $('#custom-table tr').hide();  // <-----

           $.each(selected, function(i, val) {   
               $('#custom-table tr > td:contains('+val+')').closest('tr').show();
           });
       }
    });
});
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h0Lfjqs/8/)

Comment: I never thought that it be easy. Thanks @Patel.

Comment: @myRM This happens to the best of us. Cheers! :)

Comment: demo is not working properly could you please check it and update it.